# How to print the route of a packet in hwmp ns3

Tags: ns-3

I would like to know how can i print the route of a packet in a mesh topology that implements hwmp. I don't mean the entire routing table but the intermediate nodes that a packet has traverse in order to reach the destination.

Thanks in advance,

Mary

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
YansWifiPhyHelper wifiPhy =  YansWifiPhyHelper::Default ();
....
....
....
....
AsciiTraceHelper ascii;
wifiPhy.EnableAsciiAll (ascii.CreateFileStream ("wifi-simple-adhoc-grid.tr"));
```

This will create a trace file named `wifi-simple-adhoc-grid.tr`, which you can analyse to determine the route of each packet. See example in `examples/wireless/wifi-simple-adhoc-grid.cc`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that in 802.11s networks the routing is performed at MAC layer, so the above doesn't seem to give a solution. Any other suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: The above command traces the channel, so the layer is not a problem. It seems however that 802.11s does not have EnableAsciiAll implemented yet. Thus, you should either use pcap tracing, or modify the routers so they print directly. If you solve it, please share the solution

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I can just print the packets that a mesh point receives. The output will be something like this: SRC=00:00:00:00:00:01, DST = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, I am: 00:00:00:00:00:02 packet id 3095. This can be done in mesh-point-device.cc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where, but you must be able to track packets through log files!
In the other hand, if you are interested by the **number of hops**, you can fetch that from FlowMonitor (timeForwarded metric).

> How?
>   AvrgHopCount= 1 + (flowmon.timesForwarded/flowmon.rxPackets)

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please give more tips on how to fetch the number of hops from FlowMonitor? This won't give me a solution but it will surely be something.

Answer (score 0):

You can print routing table using :

```
Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper globalRouting;
Ptr<OutputStreamWrapper> routingStream = Create<OutputStreamWrapper> ("result/leapstar2.routes", std::ios::out);
globalRouting.PrintRoutingTableAllAt (Seconds(0.1), routingStream );
```